# Spreading the markers on mouseover in Google Maps V3. (Not clusters)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am plotting some markers on a google map (API v3). If there are, say, 3-4 markers together at one place and somebody does a mouseover I want to spread them out. This way it becomes easy for anybody to click on a specific marker.

Note: I do not want to show use marker-cluster and then zoom the map on clicking the cluster.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve: 
Try doing a mouse over on this map: http://www.austria.info/uk/interactive-austria-map wherever you see some markers together. How it has been implemented? Any library / sample code for this?

Thanks for your time!
Himanshu

Comment: Hey, just looked your map. Any hint about the shadow/fade out of the other countries? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used this but it says it does what you're looking for:

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier

Comment: Thanks Eric! This seems to do the job. But the interface in the link I have sent is way more beautiful :)

Comment: Tried it! Works great apart from the fact that the spreading is not animated. Thanks Eric for the help!

Comment: I managed to make this work on mouseover rather than click for the overlapped markers and using infobox instead of the standard google infowindow. The `keepSpiderfied` option came in handy. I'm amazed this is even possible.